# Scraping giphy with selenium. Unable to retrieve the correct 'src' attribute

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, src

I am trying to scrape giphy.com with python selenium package. When I select the required attribute 'src' from the xPath, it is returning something different than is in the 'inspect' section of the website.

it returns this: giphy-gif-img giphy-img-loaded

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

whereas I am looking to extract the src element as per the website:

```
src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/j6x5zFoaJN9rAejDfZ/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47v5k8qf29vp649xd8nsbba2c0ai8m6ftuifkrnipp&amp;rid=giphy.gif&amp;ct=g"
```

Weirdly, when i was running this previously, it would get me the required element but has now stopped providing that element!

```
url = 'https://giphy.com/search/fall-over'
img_x_path = '//*[@id="react-target"]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/a[11]/div/picture/img'

#%%
#first initialise the driver and then get the webpage
def initialise_chrome():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    return driver
driver = initialise_chrome()
# then let's find the xpath element
print(driver)

#%%
x_path_req = driver.find_element_by_xpath(img_x_path)

def retrive_image_link(x_path_req):
    #first - locate the img with pre-defined x_path
    
    print(x_path_req)
    #from that, then pick the src bit
    image_link = x_path_req.get_attribute('src')
    print(image_link) 
    
 retrive_image_link(x_path_req)
```

Comment: if you get it as `data:image/gif;base64, ...` then you can use module `base64` to convert `R0lGODlhAQABAIAA ...` back to image `gif` and save it in file

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like giphy is using base64 encoded images rather than loading them from a URL source. For example I see this when I inspect the page.

```html
<a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/1stLookTV-montreal-johnny-bananas-1st-look-tv-fCUCWxvDVyuE9gLQSC" class="giphy-gif  css-r2u7fp" tabindex="0" style="width: 248px; height: 136px; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(792px, 517px, 0px);">
    <div style="width: 248px; height: 136px; position: relative;">
        <picture>
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://media4.giphy.com/media/fCUCWxvDVyuE9gLQSC/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e478y8zdwetr9wadyulcwbss0njcd0gvhp8wbw1sf59&amp;rid=200w.webp&amp;ct=g">. 
            <img class="giphy-gif-img " src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" width="248" height="136" alt="fall over wipe out GIF by 1st Look" style="background: rgb(153, 51, 255);">
        </picture>
    </div>
</a>
```

It does appear though that the `<source>` element above the `<img>` has the actual URL source in the `srcset` attribute, so maybe you can alter your XPath to extract that instead.

You could also edit you XPath to extract the `srcset` attribute too. I think it would be this instead

`//*[@id="react-target"]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/a[11]/div/picture/source/@srcset`